# Unknown Error with Javascript, nothing in developer menu (F12)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website at the moment and I want to use Javascript to change a pricing table's information to cycle through Monthly to Quarterly to Annually back to Monthly. I have fixed issues showing up in the developer menu on Firefox (F12). Currently nothing happens when I click the button including that I do not get any error messages.

I've tried changing browsers and devices however I still get no response from the javascript.

Here is the area of the website:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var m = document.getElementById("whPricingMonthly");
  var q = document.getElementById("whPricingQuart");
  var a = document.getElementById("whPricingAnnual");

  if (m.style.display === "block") {
    m.style.display === "none";
    q.style.display === "block";
  } else if (q.style.display === "block") {
    q.style.display === "none";
    a.style.display === "block";
  } else if (a.style.display === "block") {
    m.style.display === "block";
    a.style.display === "none";
  } else {
    m.style.display === "block";
    a.style.display === "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex d-sm-flex d-lg-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center">

  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-warning d-sm-flex d-lg-flex justify-content-sm-center outline" type="button">Change payment time <br>(Monthly, Quaterly, Annually)</button>

</div><br>


<div class="col comparison" id="whPricingMonthly" style="display:block;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="price-header">
        <th class="tl tl2" valign="bottom"><span class="price-options-desc">Monthly Pricing Options</span></th>
        <th class="qbse qbse-first"> Small <span class="table-price">$2<small>.80</small><span style="font-size:16px;">/pm</span></span>
        </th>
        <th class="qbse qbse-second"> Business <span class="table-price">$4<span style="font-size:16px;">/pm</span></span>
        </th>
        <th class="qbse qbse-third"> Platinum <span class="table-price">$8<span style="font-size:16px;">/pm</span></span>
        </th>
        <th class="qbse qbse-last"> Ultimate <span class="table-price">$11<span style="font-size:16px;">/pm</span></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="4">Disk Space</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compare-row">
        <td>Disk Space</td>
        <td>10GB</td>
        <td>20GB</td>
        <td>50GB</td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Bandwidth</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bandwidth</td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Email Accounts</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compare-row">
        <td>Email Accounts</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td><strong>Unlimited</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Mailing Lists</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mailing Lists</td>
        <td><span class="tickblue">✔</span></td>
        <td><span class="tickgreen">✔</span></td>
        <td><span class="tickgreen">✔</span></td>
        <td><span class="tickgreen">✔</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">MySQL Databases</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compare-row">
        <td>MySQL Databases</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><strong>Unlimited</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Subdomains</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Subdomains</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td><strong>Unlimited</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Parked Domains</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compare-row">
        <td>Parked Domains</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><strong>Unlimited</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td class="options"></td>
        <td class="package-btn pack-1"><a href="#" class="n-button n-button-grey show-free-download">Purchase</a></td>
        <td class="package-btn pack-2"><a href="#" class="n-button n-button-blue">Purchase</a></td>
        <td class="package-btn pack-3"><a href="#" class="n-button n-button-purple">Purchase</a></td>
        <td class="package-btn pack-4"><a href="#" class="n-button n-button-green">Purchase</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>



<!--             --------------------------------------------------------------            -->



<div class="col comparison" id="whPricingQuart" style="display:none;">
```

To save space and to prevent posting the whole page, I've stopped it here - it goes on alike above, the last line is how the others are set out that are hidden to start.

The expected result is that it swaps between the tables on the site setting display to "none" on the current table, and setting the next one to "block".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changed `===` to `=` inside if condition. `m.style.display = "none";`
`===` is used compare the value and `=` is used to assign values. 
let me know if you need anything else. thanks

```js
function myFunction() {
  var m = document.getElementById("whPricingMonthly");
  var q = document.getElementById("whPricingQuart");
  var a = document.getElementById("whPricingAnnual");
  
  if (m.style.display === "block") {
    m.style.display = "none";
    q.style.display = "block";
  } else if (q.style.display === "block") {
    q.style.display = "none";
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else if (a.style.display === "block") {
    m.style.display = "block";
    a.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    m.style.display = "block";
    a.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex d-sm-flex d-lg-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center">

  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-warning d-sm-flex d-lg-flex justify-content-sm-center outline" type="button">Change payment time <br>(Monthly, Quaterly, Annually)</button>

</div><br>


<div class="col comparison" id="whPricingMonthly" style="display:block;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="price-header">
        <th class="tl tl2" valign="bottom"><span class="price-options-desc">Monthly Pricing Options</span></th>
        <th class="qbse qbse-first"> Small <span class="table-price">$2<small>.80</small><span style="font-size:16px;">/pm</span></span>
        </th>
        <th class="qbse qbse-second"> Business <span class="table-price">$4<span style="font-size:16px;">/pm</span></span>
        </th>
        <th class="qbse qbse-third"> Platinum <span class="table-price">$8<span style="font-size:16px;">/pm</span></span>
        </th>
        <th class="qbse qbse-last"> Ultimate <span class="table-price">$11<span style="font-size:16px;">/pm</span></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="4">Disk Space</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compare-row">
        <td>Disk Space</td>
        <td>10GB</td>
        <td>20GB</td>
        <td>50GB</td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Bandwidth</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bandwidth</td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Unmetered</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Email Accounts</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compare-row">
        <td>Email Accounts</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td><strong>Unlimited</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Mailing Lists</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mailing Lists</td>
        <td><span class="tickblue">✔</span></td>
        <td><span class="tickgreen">✔</span></td>
        <td><span class="tickgreen">✔</span></td>
        <td><span class="tickgreen">✔</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">MySQL Databases</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compare-row">
        <td>MySQL Databases</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><strong>Unlimited</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Subdomains</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Subdomains</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td><strong>Unlimited</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4">Parked Domains</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compare-row">
        <td>Parked Domains</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><strong>Unlimited</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td class="options"></td>
        <td class="package-btn pack-1"><a href="#" class="n-button n-button-grey show-free-download">Purchase</a></td>
        <td class="package-btn pack-2"><a href="#" class="n-button n-button-blue">Purchase</a></td>
        <td class="package-btn pack-3"><a href="#" class="n-button n-button-purple">Purchase</a></td>
        <td class="package-btn pack-4"><a href="#" class="n-button n-button-green">Purchase</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>



<!--             --------------------------------------------------------------            -->



<div class="col comparison" id="whPricingQuart" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has solved the issue.

Have a great day

Comment: it stops on quarterly because you dont have a div on the page that has the id of 'whPricingAnnual'

Comment: I will mark it as answered with this when I can (it says wait 1 minute) @XenioGracias